# Is there any explanation to Bowser being able to change size?

Tags: super-mario-sunshine

Through the different games of the Mario series, we have seen Bowser changing size loads and loads of times.

Sometimes this change is shown and explained. That's the case in [Super Mario World 2: Yoshi's Island](https://youtu.be/anv1LZzX-Qw?t=1m37s) and [Yoshi's New Island](https://youtu.be/Lv_TYktjv6I?t=1m26s), where Kamek use his magic to increase Bowser's size. In [Super Mario Galaxy 2](https://youtu.be/7fYGYljLmV4?t=4m22s), his size apparently increase because of the magic of the power stars (even though his original size is already incredible).

But in Super Mario Sunshine, I didn't find any explanation about this. Bowser is just gigantic in [the final battle](https://youtu.be/zOOcRYfX9IY?t=3m23s). However, in [the final cutscene](https://youtu.be/3RlMCe6mHP0?t=1m34s), Bowser seems to be back to his original size again (you can totally compare his size with Bowser Jr. in both scenes).

Is there any explanation in a game (like a dialog or anything) for Bowser being able to change size like that? Did I miss something in the game?

Comment: He has a really fast metabolism, but sometimes he exagerates with the portions of the meal so he grows up..just to return normal after some time :P

Comment: This seems a speculative question about developer intent.

Comment: @pinckerman Again, I'm asking about real **game content** proofs. Nothing speculative. If none exists, then there would be no answer, simply.

Comment: "If none exists, then there would be an answer that there are no proofs" - fixed..there is always an answer

Comment: It's such a thin line between developer intent and in-game lore.  We're playing with magic word syndrome here, and, honestly, the Mario world lore isn't consistent enough to answer this.  They're separate games.  What happens is because Nintendo wants it to happen that way.  Voting to close as developer intent.

Comment: The fact is that there is a specific answer for Yoshi's Island episodes. There is also a specific answer for Super Mario Galaxy 2. I'm just wondering if there is also an answer in this game like there is for the other two. That's why I don't see the developer intent point there, I'm just looking for an existing fact like for the other two games. Would asking for the other two would have been off-topic as well, as we can see there is an actual in-game answer to those?

Comment: The lore for Super Mario changes with pretty much every game released, so I doubt there's a single unifying reason. It is documented (in the very first Super Mario Bros. game's instruction booklet) that Bowser has some magical ability - he turned all of Mushroom Kingdom's denizens into brick blocks. I suppose you could argue that Bowser has some inherent magical ability but is usually too dumb to use it. I don't think the question itself is off-topic though. [Lore questions are on topic after all.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7698/145980)

Comment: @MageXy Indeed. That's why I ended up making the question focused on Super Mario Sunshine, so there is no conflict with the global none unified lore from the series. I agree with Frank that, on this exact point, it could have been considered as too broad at least.
I didn't think about his magical abilities though. That's a fair point.

Comment: @Frank: A developer intent question would be "why is the lore the way it is?", whereas a lore question would be "what is the lore?". This question clearly falls in the second category. Just because the question is difficult to answer (or may not even have an answer) doesn't automatically mean it's off topic.

Comment: @MageXy No, this specific question is developer intent.  But when you add, "in the lore" to the question, it suddenly becomes on-topic.  It has nothing to do with difficulty, and everything to do with the very thin line between developer intent and lore.  With Mario games being as inconsistent as they are, I don't think it's reasonable to assume there is an explanation, and this is just a game of poke the plot hole.

Comment: @Frank I really fail to see where is the developer intent search in this question. We are talking about real in-game facts. I just showed before that there **is** explanations depending on the games. Why would Sunshine be off-topic there? It's not anything speculative, nor it does need the developer's point of view. It's a real fact being in the game. And yes, that might be a "poke the plot hole" question. But it's not because a question is not about making someone's play time easier or better that it does not provide anything. Can you explain to me what is the problem so I can understand?